# Is a bounded sequence Cauchy if the element come closer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

MISSED THE CONDITION ON THE SUP....

I try to prove the existence of a limit in a Banach space. I have a sequence $\{x_n\}$ and I have managed to prove that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|= C<\infty$ and $\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|>\|x_{n+1}-x_n\|$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is this enough to prove that the sequence is Cauchy? If not, what else does it need? I hope I don't have to prove that it is Cauchy by using the definition.

EDIT:I'll give some more information as David suggested.

My problem actually is to prove the existence of the separatrix of a map. Not to bother you with details I was an asymptotic to the separatix (that I don't know it exists). I have a real analytic map $F$ So there is a series up to any $N\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$w_N(t)=\sum_{j=1}^N w_j t^{-j}$$

with the property

$$w_N(t)-F(w_N(t-1))\in O(t^{-N-2}).$$

My conjunction is that there exists a $w(t)$ such that $w(t)=F(w(t-1))$ and moreover

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F^n(w_N(t-n))=w(t)$$

for large enough $N$. I have proven so far that

$$w_N(t)-F^n(w_N(t-n))\in O(t^{-N-1}),\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

It is easy to show that $|F^{n}(w_N(t-n))-F^{n-1}(w_N(t-n+1))|>|F^{n+1}(w_N(t-n-1))-F^{n}(w_N(t-n))|$.

I have to clarify some things that are hidden by my notation. $F$ is extended to a map $F:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ and the real part of $t$ is smaller than a negative number of my choice. So what I want to prove that the sequence of these analytic functions converge uniformly but for a start pointwise convergence will make me happy.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the sequence is? Perhaps, we can give some insight into the problem.

Comment: @DavidMitra I added few more details.

Comment: I am confused by the first line reading "MISSED THE CONDITION ON THE SUP....". Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that isn't enough. Look at $\mathbb{R}$ and the sequence $x_{2n} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8^{2n}}$, $x_{2n+1} = \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{8^{2n+1}};$ we approach $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ alternatingly and successively lower the distance, but clearly we don't converge.

Comment: Hm... So it needs some kind of monotonicity. Is there anything defined in a Banach space that will have the same effect with monotonicity in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @rom I don't know anything general...

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer.